# How to execute Union of 2 queries from different SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to execute union of 2 SQL queries from different SQL Servers as shown below in my query?

```
Select * from table1 (server 1)
union
Select * from table1 (server 2)
```

Comment: Look into linked servers.

Comment: Really, you should have [searched SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+linked+server) about this in the first instance.

Comment: Paul, I didn't know about linked server. So I think that your comment is no needed and unnecessary.

Comment: Well, in that case I searched on what you specified: [SQL queries from different SQL Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+queries+from+different+SQL+Servers).  Searching SO is a basic function of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the linked server so you have to access of that server after that You can try this way to call and execute the query.

A linked server allows for access to distributed, heterogeneous queries against OLE DB data sources. After a linked server is created, distributed queries can be run against this server, and queries can join tables from more than one data source. If the linked server is defined as an instance of SQL Server, remote stored procedures can be executed.

```
Select * from <ServerName>.<databaseName>.<SchemaName>.<Table1>
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) is the official documentation to configure the link server.

Comment: Add a link to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [linked servers](https://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server) first.

Then write your query with aliases, like this:

`SELECT r.[Project_ID], a.[Name]
FROM [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[Record] r inner join 
     [LinkedServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[Active] a
     ON r.[Project_ID] = a.[Delivery_Number];`